# Laravel 5.6, make multiple page register and save input data to session

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, laravel

I want to someone give me some advice. I'm really stuck. I'm new in laravel. I'd try to make register page with multiple page. i want to make like this:

1. first page user input some data, and then click next, data will be store to the session and redirect to second page registration
2. After that, User input some data and when user clicks finish, data will be saved to table users.

I use laravel authentication `php artisan make:auth` and modify the view and controller as I need. but when I click next button, nothing happens.

when I checked in the console it says `POST http://localhost:8000/registrasi/v2 500 (Internal Server Error)`

and when I checked in network tabs it says

```
"{,…}
exception
:
"Illuminate\Database\QueryException"
file
:
"C:\xampp\htdocs\vojo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php"
line
:
664
message
:
"SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'senderEmail' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `users` where `senderEmail` = clubband@gmail.com)"
trace
:
[{file: "C:\xampp\htdocs\vojo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php",…},…]"
```

this is my code

Web.php

```
Route::get('/', function () {
return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::group(['prefix'=>'registrasi'], function(){
Route::get('/v1','Auth\RegisterController@ShowView');
Route::post('/v2','Auth\RegisterController@store');
});
```

my migration users table

```
    <?php

   use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
   use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
   use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

   class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
   {
   /**
    * Run the migrations.
    *
    * @return void
    */
    public function up()
    {
       Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('username')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->enum('user_type', ['customer', 'band', 'admin'])- 
            >default('customer');
            $table->string('profile_picture')->nullable();
            $table->datetime('last_login')->nullable();
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
            });
     }

     /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
     }
}
```

**RegisterController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Session;
class RegisterController extends Controller
{
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register Controller
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
| validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
| provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
|
*/

use RegistersUsers;

/**
 * Where to redirect users after registration.
 *
 * @var string
 */
   protected $redirectTo = '/home';

/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
   public function __construct()
   {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

/**
 * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
 */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
            ]);


     }

/**
 * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return \App\User
 */
     protected function create(array $data)
    {
         return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
             'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);
}

protected function store(Request $request){
    $this->validate($request, [
        'senderName' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'senderEmail' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'senderUsername' => 'required|string|max:255|unique:users',
        'senderPassword' => 'required|string|min:6'
    ]);

 Session::put('SimpanRegisterBand',$request->all());

    return view('layouts.test');
}
protected function ShowView(){
    return view('Auth.register');
}
}
```

I'm sorry for my bad English. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For the error message as shown, you have an SQL error, which means you send a field "**senderEmail**" to the table which doesn't exists:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'senderEmail' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from users where senderEmail = clubband@gmail.com)
```

Second, to store data in the session, use:

```
Session::put('key',$value);
```

to get data from session, use:

```
Session::get('key')
```

don't forget to add a use line, like:

```
use Session;
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice sir. But i want to store data to session first, after that i store data to database. Any suggestion for my code that i should to change sir?

Comment: You should have two views which means two actions, so in the first action store $request->all() into the Session and redirect to the second page (view) and from that you'll go to the second action (it can be the store action in your controller) where you can store the incoming data into session, get old and new data and store them into DB

Answer (score 0):

You need a proper validation in your store() method. You need to specify the column name in unique validation, otherwise it will just take request name as a column name.

Here is the modified code.

```
protected function store(Request $request){
    $this->validate($request, [
        'senderName' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'senderEmail' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users,email',
        'senderUsername' => 'required|string|max:255|unique:users,username',
        'senderPassword' => 'required|string|min:6'
    ]);

    Session::put('SimpanRegisterBand',$request->all());

    return view('layouts.test');
}
```